# NiFi - custom orc processor gives NoClassDefFoundError for class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi, orc

I am trying to develop a custom processor in Apache NiFi which writes directly orc files into a remote hadoop cluster. In order to write them, I am using the [orc core api](https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html). I tried writing the files on the local FS and they are ok: hive, which is their "final destination" has no problem in reading them.

The issue is that, while trying to create a Writer object, I get a **NoClassDefFoundError** for the class **org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem**.

That's the code used:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfigurationPath+"/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfigurationPath+"/hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
String hdfsUri = conf.get("fs.default.name");

...

try{
    writer = OrcFile.createWriter(new Path(hdfsUri+"/"+filename+".orc"), OrcFile.writerOptions(conf).setSchema(orcSchema));
}
catch(IOException e){
    log.error("Cannot open hdfs file. Reason: "+e.getMessage());
    session.transfer(flowfile, hdfsFailure);
    return;
}
...
```

I've copied the **hadoop-hdfs** jar in the lib directory, and I tried looking runtime at the jar loaded in the classpath using ClassLoader and it can be seen. Including them in the maven dependencies does not solve the issue too.

Any suggestion on how to get rid of this error is really appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Try using Maven/Gradle rather than JAR files

Comment: It will be necessary to see much more of the configuration/setup you have for building the custom processor.  Could you share a pointer to a project in github for example?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am already using maven (I admit it's not clear as is written), and I've tried adding the dependencies without success.

Comment: @JoeWitt I will try to share the project with you but I don't know if I can do that. However, I am using NiFi 1.2 and Hadoop 2.7. The processor's project has been created from the NiFi maven archetype.

Comment: Alright, then you can show your `pom.xml`, please? You said you copied a JAR, but Maven does not need to do that.

Comment: I think you may need the Maven "shade" plugin to include the necessary dependencies into your plugin correctly.

Comment: You do not need the Maven shade plugin, the project structure created by the Maven archetype takes care of bundling all the dependencies into a single NAR. You also shouldn't need to put anything in the lib directory, your NAR should contain the hadoop-hdfs JAR inside of it. After deploying your NAR and starting NiFi, check NIFI_HOME/work/nar/extensions/nifi-YOUR-NAME.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/ and that will show you the JARs that were packaged in your NAR.

Comment: @BryanBende I've checked the folder, and the required jars are there, but with a different version w.r.t. the dependencies I added in the pom (2.7.3 vs 2.7.1) . Maybe that's due to the other dependency, orc-core 1.2.1. However, I solved the issues adding the hadoop-common to the pom and setting the defaullt implementation after gathering the hdfs uri. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@riccamini,

Please try this way it surely to be work.

Just add below dependency to your processors pom file with respect to your hadoop version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Still you cann't solve error .Then finally copy that hadoop-hdfs jar in NiFi\lib directory.

Let me know if it work for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as mentioned I already tried adding the required dependencies and it did not work out.

Comment: Riccamini,Did you try copy that jar directly into the Nifi\lib directory?

Comment: Yes, at first. But eventually I solved it adding also the **hadoop-common** dependency in the pom, and refactoring a little bit the code.